# Addition of '\slashed{}' to Latex engine

Tags: feature-request

Is it possible to add the small ['slashed'](http://mirror.unl.edu/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/carlisle/slashed.sty) package to the SE latex environment?

Comment: Just noticed: MathJax already has a `\cancel` command you can use, if you first put `\require{cancel}` (I think). http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/tex.html#cancel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not under our control. You can submit a new feature request for MathJax [here](https://github.com/mathjax/MathJax/issues).